MAUI .NET Get Unique Device ID For Windows
I'm trying to capture a unique device id for a MAUI .NET Windows app.
I have the code for IOS and Android but I simply don't know where to start for Windows. I've looked online and cannot find anything.
Can anyone help?

A search on Windows "device fingerprint" might turn up something.  Many IDs just build some sort of hash from device information, but this will change when for example the user buys a new graphics card or SSD so you need to plan for that.  Other IDs use the network adapter MAC address which also might change when they switch from wired to wifi to cell phone tethered.

https://www.google.com/search?q=.net+get+unique+device+id+site:stackoverflow.com

I am dying to know how you got "device ID" for android.

You can see this thread about Added Device ID to Essentials.DeviceInfo and follow it up.

MAUI does not provide the method to get the device ID on windows. The MAUI document here only provides the method to get Device information. Here are the properties you can use.
